# How to completely replace data object on HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

Is there any faster way to replace all of the content in an elements data object?

```
//get old data keys to delete
var old_data = $(".f")[0].dataset;

for (var key in old_data){
  delete old_data[key];
}
//new data to attach to `.f` element
var new_data = $(".s")[0].dataset;

for (var key in new_data){
  $(".f").data(key, new_data[key]);
}

console.log($(".f").data());
```

I've tried more terse variations like

```
  //errors
  $(".f").data() = {};
  $(".f").data(new_data);

  //doesn't delete old keys/values
  var new_data = $(".s").data();
  $(".f").data(new_data);
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Unfortunately that only seems to remove data attributes set explicitly with jQuery, not inline `data-sth="123"` Thank you though.

Comment: have you tried to delete the dataset itselfe like `delete $(".f")[0].dataset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use both the [jQuery .removeData](http://api.jquery.com/removedata/) and [jQuery .removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) APIs.

```
.removeData( [list] ); 
.removeAttr( [name] );
```

> [list] - An array or space-separated string naming the pieces of data
>   to delete. When called with no arguments, .removeData() removes all
>   values.

**UPDATE**

Since `.removeAttr( [name] )` 'forces' you to remove one piece at a time you may as well use:

```
.removeData( [name] );
```

Please bear in mind that `[name]` is of the form `data-<name>` and `<name>` respectively. For instance to remove `data-myid` use:

```
.removeAttr( 'data-myid' ); //and 
.removeData( 'myid' );
```

Comment: Won't be faster, i guess

Comment: `.removeAttr( [name] );` worked. No luck with `.removeData( [list] );`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since `.removeAttr( [name] )` forces you to remove one piece at a time you may as well use `.removeData( [name] )`. Please bear in mind that `[name]` is of the form `data-<name>` and `<name>` respectively. For instance to remove `data-myid` use `.removeAttr( 'data-myid' )` and `.removeData( 'myid' )`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery builinfunction `jQuery.removeData( element [, name ] )`.

See reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.removedata/)

Comment: Doesn't remove data-* attributes

Comment: Unfortunately that only seems to remove data attributes set explicitly with jQuery, not inline data-sth="123" Thank you though.